# Runtime error 1004 Range Formula

Tags: vba, excel

I spent this afternoon trying to compile a macro but I'm stuck on a runtime error :

> Application-Defined or Object-defined error.

Here's my code :

```
Sub MajPO()


Dim i As Integer

Dim FromRStart, FromREnd, ToRStart, ToREnd
Dim Technology(18) As String
Technology(0) = "ADSL"
Technology(1) = "ADTRAN"
Technology(2) = "ADVA"
Technology(3) = "AGW HUAWEI"
Technology(4) = "CISCO"
Technology(5) = "CSI DWDM HUAWEI"
Technology(6) = "IP & IP/VPN REPAIR"
Technology(7) = "JUNIPER"
Technology(8) = "MEGAPAC"
Technology(9) = "MICROWAVE HUAWEI"
Technology(10) = "POWER"
Technology(11) = "ROP HOUSING"
Technology(12) = "SDH ERICSSON"
Technology(13) = "SDH MARCONI"
Technology(14) = "SOP14XX"
Technology(15) = "SYNCRO-GILLAM"
Technology(16) = "VDSL1"
Technology(17) = "VDSL2"

For i = 0 To 18
  Worksheets("FromRepair").Activate
    FromRStart = Application.Match(Technology(i), Range("A:A"), 0)
    FromREnd = Application.Match(Technology(i) & " Total", Range("A:A"), 0)
Worksheets("MissingPO").Activate
    ToRStart = Application.Match(Technology(i), Range("A:A"), 0)
    ToREnd = Application.Match(Technology(i) & " Total", Range("A:A"), 0)

myRange = ("K" & FromRStart & ":L" & FromREnd)
Range("O" & ToRStart).Formula = "=IFNA(VLOOKUP(B6;FromRepair!" & myRange & ";11;0)"

Next



End Sub
```

And the error is in the following line  :

```
Range("O" & ToRStart).Formula = "=IFNA(VLOOKUP(B6;FromRepair!" & myRange & ";11;0)"
```

Does anyone of you know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: "=IFNA(VLOOKUP(B6;FromRepair!" & myRange & ";11;0)"

In the above code, there are 2 opening brackets and only one closing bracket. I assume you need the other one. Im not intho this technology, so this is my observation

Comment: @Vamsi : Make an answer to take the rep points! ;) (look at the comments on mine to make it complete ;) )

Comment: Glad to know you got the issue fixed. It gives me immense pleasure to see OP's issue getting resolved rather than me getting points. Happy coding. :)

Comment: That's what I love about this community. Thank you a lot @Vasmi have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

As @Vamsi said your are missing a closing bracket in your formula.

Furthermore, I'd add that you didn't specify in the `VLOOKUP` if you want an **exact or approximate match**. As **this argument is by default set to approximate**, I'd suggest that you take the habit to set it to match your purpose.

So I'd propose this :

```
Range("O" & ToRStart).Formula = "=IFNA(VLOOKUP(B6,FromRepair!" & myRange & ",11,FALSE),0)"
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your replies, @Vasmi was right I was missing brackets. Then I replaced ";" by "," and now it's working.

Comment: @HichamBenhima : Ok, glad that it works for you now. Could you validate answer to mark your issue as solved? I proposed to Vasmi to post one but he doesn't seem to care about getting the points, but as the issue is fixed, please "close" the open question ;)

Answer (score 0):

As @Vasmi said there was a missing bracket in my formula, so the resolution was :

```
Range("O" & ToRStart).Formula = "=IFNA(VLOOKUP(B6,FromRepair!" & myRange & ",11,FALSE),0)"
```

instead of

```
Range("O" & ToRStart).Formula = "=IFNA(VLOOKUP(B6,FromRepair!" & myRange & ",11,FALSE)
```